# ExtJS Gridpanel to Export to excel

Tags: extjs

How to Export gridpanel data to Excel,

Please provide samples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an excellent plugin for exporting GridPanel's data to Excel available on Ed Spencer's blog which makes this quite easy.

http://edspencer.net/2009/11/ext-ux-exporter-export-any-grid-to-excel-or-csv.html